# Why does Android Studio get into this failed state (builds but displays App(x) & doesn't want to run)?

Tags: android-studio, build-variant

Notice that little red x on the app button?  It means I cannot run, even though it builds.

[image: Android Studio App State]

Running version 4.2.1 of Android Studio:

[image: Android Studio version]

Then, if I try to run, I see the following:

[image: needs to be signed]

Clicking the [Fix] button displays the following:

[image: meaningless dialog]

Answer (score 0):

As I was writing up the question, I stumbled upon the answer.

The answer is that my build variant was set to Release:

[image: build-variant]

I changed it to Debug and that fixed it.

That's interesting though, because I can build the release version and I do have a signing cert but it couldn't find it this time.  Very confusing.